# Bigquery. What does "Adding NULLABLE or REPEATED columns at the end" mean?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to update table in Bigquery.
Here is a documentation that says what can and can not be done:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#updateschema
It says:

> Allowed operations include:
>
> ```
> Adding NULLABLE or REPEATED columns at the end
> Making REQUIRED fields NULLABLE
> ```

I was able to update table by inserting NULLABLE and REPEATED fields, nested in my schema.

I don't understand what does "at the end" part mean.
Isn't it an internal detail about how Bigquery stores data?

Answer (score 1):

I guess documentation talks about logical order that you see when browsing table or doing "select *".
The physical storage is implementation detail, but logical order is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add columns only to the end of the structure only. You cannot reorder columns or add a column in the middle, like 2nd column.